# Debugging battery life

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery

I have a factory new MacBook Pro 2019. Supposedly I should get 11 hours of battery life but I don't even get 3. Fully charged at 23:28. Now it's 2:20 with 12% left:

[image]

Normal web browsing, email etc, no heavy CPU loads. Inside, the display brightness is at ~1/3.

Device is hot, fan (silently) blowing.
I can't find anything suspicious in the Activity Monitor. Idle shows ~93-96%. Largest consumers are WindowServer, coreaudiod and a few others.

Here is CPU History:

[image]

Comment: You could try resetting the SMC. After that, I would take it to an Apple Store or other Apple shop and let them diagnose it. If it's faulty, then they'll be able to replace it (probably free of charge); if it's not faulty, then you'll at least rule out a hardware problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `System Management Controller` is responsible, among other things, for the power supply and the battery, state of charge. I recommend you reset the [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) first.